# Этимология слов

Tags: этимология

Русскоязычный викисловарь содержит словарные статьи, посвященные словам разных языков. Какая из статей описывает слово не русского, а украинского языка?

Вампука, наморивший, оттяпывать, схорон, кристалограф

---

Догадалась, кристалограф - с одним «л» только в украинском.

Answer (score 1):

Pingvin, скорее всего неправильная формулировка. В русском нет слово "схорон", скорее всего его нет и в нормативном украинском.

Там есть слово схрон - новодел, заимствованный из русского, и классическое украинское "кривка" (крывка) с тем же значением. Откуда вообще взялось "схорон" я просто не представляю.

В украинском действительно есть слово "схоронить" - спрятать, укрыть, оно есть и в диалектном русском, но никак "схорон" не порождает.

Впрочем, есть в украинском слово "схор**о**на" - *хранение*, родительный множественного (родовий відмінок множинного) - *схорон*. Т.е. в принципе такое слово (падежная форма) в украинском может существовать, но одно никак не может быть заколовком словарной статьи.

Есть в украинском довольно распространенное слово наморивший (от наморити), но оно есть и в русском.

Аналогично - вампука. "Оттяпывать" очевидно не может быть украинским словом.

Так что остается только гадать, что имел в виду автор вопроса. Или формулировка неправильная или опечатка.

//-----------------

Я был прав. **В вопросе пропущено слово "кристалограф" (авторская правка). Очевидно, оно и есть искомый ответ.** Впрочем, я рад, что не поддался ложным версиям.

Answer (score -1):

Схорон - этимологический украинизм, по-русски - схрон.

[Заимствовано из украинского языка; украинское схрон с тем же значением образовано от гл. схоронити «спрятать».](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD)

Вампука - авторское ([вам пук цветов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0)), наморить (тараканов) и оттяпать (кусман) - русские-прерусские...

Comment: Поставил было плюс, а зря.)))

Comment: У украинском нет слова "Схорон". "Схрон", "тайник" по-украински "кривка" (=крывка). И даже если есть, ваш текст непонятен. Украинское схрон действительно от "схоронить", но при чем тут "схорон"?

Comment: Бегемотус, ссылка кликабельна! Этимологию из головы не берут: тугамент нужон. А "схорон" - последнее слово в вопросе.

Comment: То что ссылка кликабельна - это единственное, что в ваших словах правда. Остальное не поддается пониманию. По ссылке нет указания на слово "схорон".